# laravel-graphql filter query

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

how can i define a posts query that show only published post?
i dont want to use `where condition` like this.

```
 posts(@where(operator: "=", "publish", "1")): [Post!]!  @paginate
```

i want the server posts's query take only published post by default

**client:**

```
$: posts = queryStore({
    client: getContextClient(),
    query: gql`
        query ($first: Int!, $page: Int!) {
            posts(first: $first, page: $page) {
                data {
                    id
                    title
                    image
                    excerpt
                    slug
                    view
                    like
                    is_bookmarked
                    is_liked
                    author
                    postCategories {
                        id
                        title
                    }
                }
                paginatorInfo {
                    total
                    currentPage
                    lastPage
                    perPage
                    hasMorePages
                }
            }
        }
    `,
    variables: { first, page },
    requestPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
})
```

**server schema:**

```
type Query {
    posts: [Post!]!  @paginate 

}

type PostComment{
    id: ID!
    post_id: ID!
    user_id: ID
    author: String
    comment: String!
    like: Int!
    dislike: Int!
    report_count: Int!
    publish: Boolean!
    is_liked: Boolean
    is_bookmarked: Boolean
    post: Post! @belongsTo
    created_at: String
    updated_at: String

}

type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    slug: String!
    view: Int!
    like: Int!
    body: String!
    image: String
    excerpt: String
    author: String
    publish: Boolean!
    highlight: Boolean!
    is_liked: Boolean
    created_at: String
    is_bookmarked: Boolean
    postCategories: [PostCategory!]! @belongsToMany
    postComments: [PostComment!]! @hasMany

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [laravel scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes). Add a local scopePublished to the post model:

```
public function scopePublished($query)
{
    return $query->where('publish', '=', 1);
}
```

Then use it inside your schema by [`@paginate`](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/api-reference/directives.html#paginate):

```
 posts: [Post!]! @paginate(scopes: "published")
```